# How to represent a response body in xml

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, response

Hello i'm using spring framework and the default representation is in JSON. I am attempting to represent the response body in 3 formats. Xml, json and html. Default way is json but having trouble in representing in xml and html. how would you want the response body to be in xml and html. I get a 406 error when running the code.

in my pom xml: i declared

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and in my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"  >
           <property name="messageConverters">
               <list>
                   <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
                   <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
                   <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                   <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
                   <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
               </list>
           </property>

       </bean>
```

And finally my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="person/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, params="format=xml", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> PersoninXML(@PathVariable("id")Long id) {
        Person person = personDAO.findById(id);
        if(person!=null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Person>(person, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Id doesn't exist", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790998/spring-boot-return-json-and-xml-from-controllers . See this link

Comment: @VinayPrajapati i am trying to view through rest advanced client/postman and not through a .jsp page

Comment: @VinayPrajapati also i added XmlRootElement in my Pojo Object as well but still no luck

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html. Please go through the doc link

Comment: @VinayPrajapati i'm still running into error as i cannot display it in xml. I know it has to do with my configuration in dispatcher. Please could you assist me.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati i also added dependencies in maven as you showed me from the documentation