# Unable to fetch XML object via GET call in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, request-mapping

> I am using Spring boot version 2 and JAVA version 8. I am using the "produces" attribute to convert the response object to XML type, but when I do a GET call in POSTMAN app, I am getting the error as shown in the attached image.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/topics", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ArrayList<String> topicList() {
        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
        ar.add("Groceries");
        ar.add("Clothes");
        return ar;
    }
```

[image: Postman response]

> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What annotations are on the class?

Comment: @RestController . Only this

Answer (score 0):

> First I added this dependency into pom.xml of my project:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

> Then added the below code block to the class from which I was expecting the return:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

 @XmlRootElement
 public class MyClass {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/topics", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ArrayList<String> topicList() {
       ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
       ar.add("Groceries");
       ar.add("Clothes");
       return ar;
    }

 }
```

> Got my answer from this post: [Spring-boot return json and xml from controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790998/spring-boot-return-json-and-xml-from-controllers)